# Replace snapshot with qualifier tycho

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3, tycho

I'm building my eclipse plugin by using Tycho(0.19).

In **MENIFEST.MF** My plugin ID is `1.0.0.qualifier`, In pom file for same plgugin there is no version because master pom has version `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` (Even I tried to put version in plugin also but same result)

When I ran the build I'm getting my plugin as `PLUGIN_NAME.1.0.0.SNAPSHOT.jar`

**Ques:** Why in build jar file SNAPSHOT is not replacing with timestamp ?. What I'm missing..?

---

**Master POM**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin.releng</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                  <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                  <extensions>true</extensions>
              </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

     ....

</project>
```

---

**Plugin POM**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>my.plugin</artifactId>
  <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
  <parent>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugin.releng</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../plugin.releng</relativePath>
  </parent>
</project>
```

---

**Console Output**

```
[INFO] --- tycho-packaging-plugin:0.19.0:build-qualifier (default-build-qualifier) @ my.plugin ---
[INFO] The project's OSGi version is 1.0.0.201403281132
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tycho-packaging-plugin:0.19.0:validate-id (default-validate-id) @ my.plugin ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tycho-packaging-plugin:0.19.0:validate-version (default-validate-version) @ my.plugin ---
[INFO]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar file name is controlled by `finalName`. If you take a look inside the Manifest file in this jar, it will show the correct qualified version.

If you create a p2 repository with your plugins, they will contain the correct filenames.

From a maven point of view, the coordinates must match the POM and therefore the version is still -SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 0):

I believe @blackbuild is correct.

Run maven package to create a version of the jar. A SNAPSHOT version will look like this:

- org.XXX-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

But, when you deploy the SNAPSHOT to a repository, maven will set the version number. It will look like this in the repository:

- org.XXX-1.0.0-20121231.173602-4.jar

Notice that the maven deploy translates the word SNAPSHOT to a version.
See http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html